# Identify Similar Strings in Python

Tags: python

I have generated an edited DNA sequencing file that has individual reads on different lines. And would like to eliminate those that match within one character of another line.

Input file:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA    #Start checking at line 1
TTTTTTTTTTTT    #Diff by >1 char: Keep
AAAAACAAAAAA    #Diff by 1 char: Delete
AAAAACAAACAA    #Diff by 2 char: Keep
AAAAAAAAAAAA    #Diff by <1 char: Delete
```

Output file:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA
TTTTTTTTTTTT
AAAAACAAACAA
```

What I have so far:

```
with open(current_file, 'r') as f:
    lineCharsList = []
    outLines = []
    for line in f:
        lineChars = line[:]

        if not (lineChars in lineCharsList):    #exactly matches lines, need partial matching
            lineCharsList.append(lineChars)
            outLines.append(line)
            print line
```

Comment: Correct, by both. So ATA is different from the string AAT which is different from AAA. Does that help clarify?

Comment: There are several packages that can help you out with this. [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) is very easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install python-levenshtein` and use the function [`Levenshtein.hamming`](https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html#Levenshtein-hamming) to compare the strings.

> `hamming(string1, string2)` Compute Hamming distance of two strings.
>
> The Hamming distance is simply the number of differing characters.
>   That means the length of the strings must be the same.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> >>> hamming('Hello world!', 'Holly grail!') 7
> >>> hamming('Brian', 'Jesus') 5
> ```

The code is:

```
import Levenshtein

input_lines = [
    "AAAAAAAAAAAA",
    "TTTTTTTTTTTT",    # Diff by >1 char: Keep
    "AAAAACAAAAAA",    # Diff by 1 char: Delete
    "AAAAACAAACAA",    # Diff by 2 char: Keep
    "AAAAAAAAAAAA",    # Diff by <1 char: Delete
    ]
output_lines = []

for current_line in input_lines:
    for previous_line in output_lines:
        if Levenshtein.hamming(previous_line, current_line) < 2:
            break
    else:
        output_lines.append(current_line)

print('\n'.join(output_lines))
```

output:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA
TTTTTTTTTTTT
AAAAACAAACAA
```

Comment: there are two typos in the link and text (the import is correct: Levenshtein)

Comment: upvoted, excellent answer, thank you. I was playing with it by hand and I realised it would not be easy peasy

Answer (score 1):

You got an excellent answer already.

Here is my implementation in basic python

```
with open(current_file, 'r') as f:
    outlines = []
    for line in f:
        z = zip(line, *[el for el in outlines])
        matches = [el[0] in el[1:] for el in z]
        if matches.count(False) > 1:
            outlines.append(line)
```